# Find the change of coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

i'm having trouble figuring out how to approach this problem. i've been able to solve similar problems involving vectors, but this one involves polynomials and i can't find a useful example for how to deal with it.

$A$ and $B$ are pairs of ordered bases for second degree polynomials. i need to find the change of coordinate matrix from $A$ coordinates to $B$ coordinates.

for the first question, $A = \{1, x, x^2\}$ and $B = \{2x^2-x, 3x^2+1, x^2\}$

i know i'm supposed to express each element of $A$ as a linear combination of all elements in $B$, e.g.,

$1 = a(2x^2-x)+b(3x^2+1)+c(x^2)$

but i can't remember how to set this up as a matrix. i know i'm supposed to collect coefficients and then arrange them in rows according to the order of their corresponding variables. e.g.,

$1 = (2a+3b+c)x^2+(-a)x+(b)$

i think i need a row for the coefficients of the $x^2$ term, the $x$ term and the constant term, but i don't know what to set them equal to here.

what should i do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, solve the system:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a+3b+c=0\\-a=0\\b=1.\end{array}\right.$$The solution will be $a=-\frac32$, $b=1$, and $c=0$. In other words, the first element of $A$ is $-\frac32\times(2x^2-x)+1\times(3x^2+1)+0\times x^2$. So, the entries of the first column of your matrix will be $-\frac32$, $1$, and $0$.

Now, do the same thing with the second and the third elements of $A$.

Comment: should my matrix be the one below? for this first operation.
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: A change of basis matrix is *always* a square matrix.

Comment: i was referring to the matrix version of the system of equations you gave me. anyway, your answer was very helpful. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The transistion matrix from $B$ to $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\2&3&1\end{pmatrix}$.  So if you invert this matrix, you will have it.